# Changing action titles in interactive notifications at run time

Tags: ios, interactive

As per my understanding I have to register categories and actions therein for local or remote interactive notifications, now my requirement is that I want to show buttons with dynamic titles coming as part of the push payload.

As an alternative I have also tried the option of firing a local notification with settings registered when a remote notification is received, but somehow it is not working and the local notification is not fired. Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't change the action button title at runtime.

BUT, you can try the following:

1. Before sending a notification to the device, send it a "silent" notification, using the `content-available` property. In this notification, send a data which represent your new action button titles.
2. Update your relevant category using `registerUserNotificationSettings:`.
3. Send the "real" notification with the new action titles, you've just created.

It need to be tested, as I never tried it in a production mode. Also, take into consideration, that you're going to double up your notification sent amount.

Comment: This answer is not correct. You can create a Notification Service extension and re-register the custom notification by running UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories with the new buttons you want to display during runtime during the didReceive event on this extension. Do not do it in a Notification Content extension you need to use a Notification Service extension

Answer (score 2):

For someone looking for this question's solution

1.Create a notification service extension

2. In didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler

create action buttons and register the category again to Notification Center

For ex:

```
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    NSDictionary * userInfo = request.content.userInfo;
NSArray * actionButtons = [userInfo valueForKeyPath:@"payload.actionButton"];

 if(actionButtons){

    NSMutableArray * buttons = [NSMutableArray new];

    for(NSDictionary * actionButton in actionButtons){

        UNNotificationAction *ActionBtn = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:[actionButton valueForKey:@"actionDeeplink"] title:[actionButton valueForKey:@"actionName"] options:UNNotificationActionOptionNone];
        [buttons addObject:ActionBtn];

    }

    UNNotificationCategory *category = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"myNotificationCategory" actions:buttons intentIdentifiers:@[] options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionNone];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:category];

    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setNotificationCategories:categories];

  }

}
```

Then in your notification payload do something like this :

```
    {
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
        "title" : "Manish Malviya",
        "body" : "iOS Developer"
        },
        "mutable-content" : 1,
    "content-available" : 1,
        "category" : "myNotificationCategory"
    },
    "payload" : {"actionButton": [
      {
        "actionName": "Yes",
        "actionDeeplink": "nottest"
      },
      {
        "actionName": "May be",
        "actionDeeplink": "tes"
      },
      {
        "actionName": "No",
        "actionDeeplink": "test"
      }
    ]
    }
 }
```

and voila see the output.

Comment: json & button is created but notification is showing without action button. Please guide me.

Comment: did you add category under UNNotificationExtensionCategory in plist?

Comment: It is required to add category in case of Service extension, As per my understanding Content extension required this type of addition in their plist file. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thats what I mean add that in its respected extension plist

Answer (score 0):

As @Asaf stated, need to re register with relevant category using registerUserNotificationSettings:

Just use the below code to achieve this :

```
 let actionAnswer  = UserNotificationAction(title: kAnswerEventTitle, identifier: kAnswerEventIdentitfier, activationMode: .Foreground, authenticationRequired: false, isDestructive: false)
        let actionReject  = UserNotificationAction(title: kRejectEventTitle, identifier: kRejectEventIdentitfier, activationMode: .Background, authenticationRequired: false, isDestructive: true)
registerModiifedUserNotificationCategory(userActions)
```

---

```
//For Notification Actions - object
struct UserNotificationAction {
    var title: String
    var identifier: String
    var activationMode: UIUserNotificationActivationMode
    var authenticationRequired: Bool
    var isDestructive:Bool

    init(title: String, identifier: String, activationMode: UIUserNotificationActivationMode? = .Background, authenticationRequired: Bool? = false, isDestructive: Bool? = false){
        self.title = title
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.activationMode = activationMode!
        self.authenticationRequired = authenticationRequired!
        self.isDestructive = isDestructive!
    }
}


  //func for dynamic UIMutableUserNotificationCategory and UIMutableUserNotificationAction creation
    func createCategoryUserNotification(notificationActions: [UserNotificationAction]) -> UIMutableUserNotificationCategory {

        var UserNotificationActions = [UIMutableUserNotificationAction]()

        for userAction in notificationActions {
            let actionItem = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            actionItem.activationMode = userAction.activationMode
            actionItem.title = userAction.title
            actionItem.identifier = userAction.identifier
            actionItem.destructive = userAction.isDestructive
            actionItem.authenticationRequired = userAction.authenticationRequired
            UserNotificationActions.append(actionItem)
        }

        var runTimeCategoryUserNotification: UIMutableUserNotificationCategory{
            let userCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
            userCategory.identifier = getGenericCategoryIdentifier(notificationActions)
            userCategory.setActions(UserNotificationActions, forContext:.Default)
            return userCategory
        }
        return runTimeCategoryUserNotification
    }

 //Re-Registering USer notification, if any new Categories required
    func registerModiifedUserNotificationCategory( notificationActions: [UserNotificationAction])-> Bool {

        // let UwerNotification = UserNotificationActions()
        let newCategory = createCategoryUserNotification(notificationActions)

        let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

        if settings!.types == .None {
            return false
        }

        let oldUserNotificationsettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

        var newCategories:[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory] = [UIMutableUserNotificationCategory]()
        var isNewCategoryFoundInExist: Bool = false

        for category in (oldUserNotificationsettings?.categories)! {
            if category.identifier == newCategory.identifier{
                isNewCategoryFoundInExist = true
            }

            if category.identifier ==  kGeneralCategoryUserNotification{//if any predefined Categories
                newCategories.append(generalCategoryUserNotification)

            }else if category.identifier ==  kCallCategoryUserNotification{//if any predefined Categories
                newCategories.append(callCategoryUserNotififation)

            }/* else{// some XYZ Category registered at runtime and if still want to Re-register
             let actions = category.actionsForContext(.Default)
             print(category.actionsForContext(.Default))

             if actions?.count > 0 {
             var genericCategoryUserNotififation: UIMutableUserNotificationCategory{
             let userCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
             userCategory.identifier = UwerNotification.getGenericCategoryIdentifierFromUserNotifAction(actions!)
             userCategory.setActions(actions, forContext:.Default)
             return userCategory
             }
             newCategories.append(genericCategoryUserNotififation )
             }
             }*/

        }

        //REgister with new category of Notification if any
        if !isNewCategoryFoundInExist {
            newCategories.append(newCategory)


                var categories =  Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>()
                for categr in newCategories{
                    categories.insert(categr)
                }
                let settings =  UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes:[.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: categories)

               //Register here registerUserNotificationSettings
        }

        return true

    }


    // generic Category Identifer based on concat of Action Identifiers
    func getGenericCategoryIdentifier(notificationActions: [UserNotificationAction]) -> String {
        let  actionIdentifiers = notificationActions.map({$0.identifier})
        let genericCategoryIdentifier = actionIdentifiers.joinWithSeparator("")
        return genericCategoryIdentifier
    }
```

Comment: where should I place these methods in ?