# Creating UNNotificationCategory in Notification Service Extension Not Working Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, notification-service-extension

For my app, I don't have a finite set of buttons that need to be supported. Instead, we are sending the buttons within the notification payload. Because of this, I need to be able to create the UNNotificationCategory on the fly, each time a notification is received with the buttons within the payload.

In order to accomplish this, I create a Notification Service Extension to intercept the notification, parse the payload, create the categories, and update the category of the push notification. That all seems doable but in practice, when creating the UNNotificationCategory from within the Notification Service Extension, the push notification does not have the actions for that cateogory.

Testing:
I've put a block of code in FinishedLaunching to print out all the UNNotificationCategories and it always returns empty. I'm not sure if this is reasonable info, though, since I'm not sure if FinishedLaunching runs before the Notification Externsion. I had a feeling that the UNUserNotificationCenter.Current instance was different between projects but I created a test library project where I created Categories and they were available back within the main project.

Other Notes:
When creating test UNNotificationCategories within FinishedLaunching and then only updating the categoryID of the push notification in the Notification Extension it works. But this isn't dynamic.

Why aren't the categories I create in the Notification Service Extension available to the push notification?

Code:

AppDelegate.cs (Main Project)

```
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            IOSMigrationHelper migrationHelper = new IOSMigrationHelper();
            // must be done before Firebase.Core.App.Configure() to migrate the saved fcm token
            // and before LoadApplication() so we don't run the initial setup process
            // and after Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init() so we can use DependencyService
            migrationHelper.Migrate();
            Forms9Patch.iOS.Settings.Initialize(this);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            bool success = base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);

            if (success)
            {
                AllGesturesRecognizer allGesturesRecognizer = new AllGesturesRecognizer(delegate
                {
                    SessionManager.Instance.ExtendSession();
                });

                Window.AddGestureRecognizer(allGesturesRecognizer);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppPreferences.DeviceIdentifier))
            {
                // this will change if the user removes and reinstalls the app but there isn't anything else to use 
                AppPreferences.DeviceIdentifier = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.ToString();
            }

            // Test Categories. Creating them here and then just updating the categoryID in the notification extension works
            var actions1 = new List<UNNotificationAction>();
            var action11 = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier($"C1 B1", "C1 B1", UNNotificationActionOptions.None); // TODO: change to foregound if urlaction != post
            var action12 = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier($"C1 B2", "C1 B2", UNNotificationActionOptions.None);

            var actions2 = new List<UNNotificationAction>();
            var action21 = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier($"C2 B1", "C2 B1", UNNotificationActionOptions.None);
            var action22 = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier($"C2 B2", "C2 B2", UNNotificationActionOptions.None);

            actions1.Add(action11);
            actions1.Add(action12);

            actions2.Add(action21);
            actions2.Add(action22);

            var intentIDs = new string[] { };
            var category1 = UNNotificationCategory.FromIdentifier("cat1", actions1.ToArray(), intentIDs, UNNotificationCategoryOptions.AllowInCarPlay | UNNotificationCategoryOptions.AllowAnnouncement);
            var category2 = UNNotificationCategory.FromIdentifier("cat2", actions2.ToArray(), intentIDs, UNNotificationCategoryOptions.AllowInCarPlay | UNNotificationCategoryOptions.AllowAnnouncement);

            // Register category
            var categories = new UNNotificationCategory[] { category1, category2 };
            UserNotificationCenter.Current.SetNotificationCategories(new NSSet<UNNotificationCategory>(categories));
            PrintCategories();

            SetupPushNotifications(app);
            return success;
        }

        async void PrintCategories()
        {
            try
            {
                NSSet<UNNotificationCategory> categories = await iOSNotificationCenter.Current.GetNotificationCategoriesAsync();

                // Categories is null when the categories created in the AppDelegate are commented out and moved to the Notification Extension
                if (categories == null)
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert($"No categories", "", "Ok");
                    return;
                }

                foreach (UNNotificationCategory c in categories)
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert($"Category: {c.Identifier}", "", "Ok");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(e.ToString(), "", "Ok");
            }
        }
```

NotificationService.cs (Notification Service Extension)

```
public override void DidReceiveNotificationRequest(UNNotificationRequest request, Action<UNNotificationContent> contentHandler)
{
    ContentHandler = contentHandler;
    BestAttemptContent = (UNMutableNotificationContent)request.Content.MutableCopy();

    var categoryID = "but1";

    // creating the categories in the notification service extension doesn't work. The notification doesn't have any buttons 
    var actions = new List<UNNotificationAction>();
    var action1 = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier($"Button 1", "Button 1", UNNotificationActionOptions.None);
    var action2 = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier($"Button 2", "Button 2", UNNotificationActionOptions.None);

    actions.Add(action1);
    actions.Add(action2);

    var intentIDs = new string[] { };
    var category = UNNotificationCategory.FromIdentifier(categoryID, actions.ToArray(), intentIDs, UNNotificationCategoryOptions.AllowInCarPlay | UNNotificationCategoryOptions.AllowAnnouncement);

    //// Register category
    var categories = new UNNotificationCategory[] { category };
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.SetNotificationCategories(new NSSet<UNNotificationCategory>(categories));

    BestAttemptContent.CategoryIdentifier = categoryID;
    ContentHandler(BestAttemptContent);
}
```

Comment: "I'm not sure if FinishedLaunching runs before the Notification Externsion" Push notifications do not launch the app (with the exception of Voip pushes). If an app-directed push is sent, then if the app is terminated, it does not get launched and the push is not delivered to it, if its already running then the push is delivered but the app is already running so its not launched.  If a user-directed push is sent, the app is not launched.

Comment: @Piepants remote notifications will still be received, and displayed to the user, even if the app is terminated. I don't need the push notification to launch the app upon received, I just need to edit it. All of this does work. The only thing that I am struggling with is creating the categories from the Extension. There is an equivalent solution for swift in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103867/changing-action-titles-in-interactive-notifications-at-run-time but it is not working when converting to Xamarin

Comment: Maybe you could try this: [Working with Notification Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#working-with-notification-actions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer, though it doesn't seem like the correct one.

Stumbling across https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios12/notifications/dynamic-actions, the "Action buttons in the notification content extension" section briefly mentions using the `ViewController's` `ExtensionContext` to call `SetNotificationActions()`. This does work.

Full Solution:

```
        public void DidReceiveNotification(UNNotification notification)
        {
            var content = notification.Request.Content;

            var actions = new List<UNNotificationAction>();
            List<SimplePushNotificationButton> buttons = new List<SimplePushNotificationButton>();

            if (content.UserInfo.TryGetValue(new NSString("buttonJSON"), out NSObject buttonsObject))
            {
                string buttonsString = buttonsObject.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buttonsString))
                {
                    buttons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SimplePushNotificationButton>>(buttonsString);
                    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // use the button text within the action id so we can match them later in AppDelegate.HandlePushNotificationButton
                        // TODO: add icon?
                        var action = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier(
                            $"{Guid.NewGuid()}_{buttons[i].Text}",
                            buttons[i].Text, buttons[i].Action.URLAction == URLAction.Post ? UNNotificationActionOptions.None : UNNotificationActionOptions.Foreground);

                        actions.Add(action);
                    }
                }
            }

            // This is what actually adds the buttons
            ExtensionContext.SetNotificationActions(actions.ToArray());
        }

        [Export("didReceiveNotificationResponse:completionHandler:")]
        public void DidReceiveNotification(UNNotificationResponse response, Action<UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption> completionHandler)
        {
            // We want to handle the button tap in the main project, not this one
            completionHandler(UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption.DismissAndForwardAction);
        }
```

I don't think this is the best solution as no where else is it recommended to use the Extension Context to add buttons. Everywhere else, even Apple's official documentation, says to create a Category with the Actions and then make sure your notification has a matching CategoryID.

The only slight downside of this solution is the buttons take about a second to show up after 3D touching the notification due to `DidReceiveNotification` not running until then.